# Can I get a simpler explanation of how array hierarchy of items in a treemap using plotly.js works?

Tags: javascript, plotly.js

I want to use the treemap feature of plotly.js and after reading the documentation I still don't understand how to customize item hierarchies.

In my mind , I imagine a tree hierarchy expressed in code as something like this:

```
{
   parent:{ "topItem"},
   topItem: {"one","two","three"},   /* children of top-item */
   one:{"something"},   /* child of "one" */
   two: {"thing", "whatever"} /* a couple of children of "two" */

}
```

I know there are better ways to do this, but my point is that this style maps to how I think about nested relationships of data.

In the plotly.js treemap example code, the relationship between the data and the rendered output confuses me and I don't understand how to think about it.

The example(s) use a couple of arrays to express nested item relationships and they typically look like this:

```
data = [{
      type: "treemap",
      labels: ["Eve", "Cain", "Seth", "Enos", "Noam", "Abel", "Awan", "Enoch", "Azura"],
      parents: ["", "Eve", "Eve", "Seth", "Seth", "Eve", "Eve", "Awan", "Eve" ]
}]

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data)
```

This example renders the hierarchy displayed here : https://plotly.com/javascript/treemaps/

If I wanted to add three children to the "Cain" block (or any other change for that matter), I have no idea how to do that and I would like to learn.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to take a JSON hierarchy like yours as an example:

```
{
    "root": { "topItem" },
    "topItem": { "one", "two", "three" },
    "one": { "something" },
    "two": { "thing", "whatever" }
}
```

First you take all of the elements you want to render and put them in the labels array, just listing them one after the other:

```
labels: ["root", "topItem", "one", "two", "three", "something", "thing", "whatever"]
```

Then for each of the elements in `labels`, you have to specify its parent element in the hierarchy. `labels[0]` is called `root` and it does not have a parent, so we leave `parents[0] = ""`. `labels[1]` is `topItem` and according to the JSON, its parent is `root`, so `parents[1] = "root"`. `labels[2]`, `labels[3]` and `labels[4]` ("one", "two", "three") all have the same parent, so `parents[2] = parents[3] = parents [4] = "topItem"`, and so on.
You end up with

```
parents: ["", "root", "topItem", "topItem", "topItem", "one", "two", "two" ]
```

See the example below:

```js
const data = [{
      type: "treemap",
      labels: ["root", "topItem", "one", "two", "three", "something", "thing", "whatever"],
      parents: ["", "root", "topItem", "topItem", "topItem", "one", "two", "two" ]
}]

Plotly.newPlot('chart', data)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.20.0.min.js"></script>

<div id='chart'></div>
```